# how to update value in mongodb using mongoose?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I make a simple demo of MongoDB in node js .

first I save my `document` like this which is working fine .

```
{
"_id": "5d984cf947cd7301dab539be",
"tmObj": {
"a1": "N",
"a2": "N",
"a3": "N"
},
"__v": 0
}
```

now I want to update one `attribute from my collection`

example data is

```
const data = {
      a1: "Y"
    };
```

here is my code

https://codesandbox.io/s/objective-minsky-bqeil

```
app.get("/saveData", async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const data = {
      tmObj: {
        a1: "N",
        a2: "N",
        a3: "N"
      }
    };
    console.log("before save");
    let blog = new BlogPostModel(data);
    let saveBlog = await blog.save(data); //when fail its goes to catch
    return res.send(saveBlog);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    return res.status(400).send(error);
  }
});

app.get("/update", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const data = {
      a1: "Y"
    };
    let filterBlog = await BlogPostModel.find({});
    //when fail its goes to catch
    console.log(filterBlog); //when success it print.
    res.send(filterBlog);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
});
```

any update?

Comment: What exactly do you want to update? `a1` field?

Comment: yes.!! I want to update `a1`

Comment: then use `myCollection.updateOne({}, {'tmObj.a1': data.a1})`

Comment: Please note that the **only** reason the code `myCollection.updateOne({}, {'tmObj.a1': data.a1})` works is because Mongoose automatically adds the [`$set`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/set/) operator for you. The real things you should be *learning* are usage of `$set` and the usage of ["dot notation"](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/#dot-notation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/snowy-meadow-j8fuv)

As you mentioned in comments that there will be only one document in the collection then you can use an empty query. To update and get the document back you can use `findOneAndUpdate`:

```
app.get("/update", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const data = {
      a1: "Y"
    };
    let filterBlog = await BlogPostModel.findOneAndUpdate(
      {},
      { "tmObj.a1": data.a1 }
    );
    //when fail its goes to catch
    console.log(filterBlog); //when success it print.
    res.send(filterBlog);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
});
```

To avoid deprecation warning you should add an option `{ useFindAndModify: false }` in `mongoose.connect`.

Comment: see not working https://codesandbox.io/s/cocky-water-cf8j8

Comment: @user944513 you made a mistake there. Check again and try to find that by yourself.

Comment: @user944513 Your comments and the fact that you accepted this answer contradict each other. Please consider deleting the comments or unaccepting this answer.